# How do I interpolate my data for plotting in python without using griddata?

Tags: python

It appears griddata is no longer in matplotlib. In my python script below, I plot point values given at longitude/latitude points. I used griddata (8 years ago) to interpolate my data onto an eqally spaced grid, using griddata. Now I am getting the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'griddata' from 'matplotlib.mlab'
I will appreciate if I could be assisted to achieve the interpolation without using griddata. A sample of data used (read from a file in the script)  is included at the end of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata as gd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

# set up plot
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# grab data
colnames=['Lon', 'Lat', 'Z']
data = pd.read_csv('./dec11-20Rn.txt',names=colnames, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
norm = Normalize()

# define map extent
lllon = 21
lllat = -18
urlon = 34
urlat = -8

# Set up Basemap instance
m = Basemap(
projection = 'merc',
llcrnrlon = lllon, llcrnrlat = lllat, urcrnrlon = urlon, urcrnrlat = urlat,
 resolution='h')

# transform lon / lat coordinates to map projection
data['Lon'], data['Lat'] = m(*(data.Lon.values, data.Lat.values))

# grid data
numcols, numrows = 1000, 1000
xi = np.linspace(data['Lon'].min(), data['Lon'].max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(data['Lat'].min(), data['Lat'].max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# interpolate
zi = gd(
    (data[['Lon', 'Lat']]),
    data.Z.values,
    (xi, yi),
    method='cubic')

# draw map details
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color = 'white')
m.fillcontinents(color='#C0C0C0', lake_color='#7093DB')
m.drawcountries(
    linewidth=.75, linestyle='solid', color='#000073',
    antialiased=True,
    ax=ax, zorder=3)
m.drawparallels(
    np.arange(lllat, urlat, 2.),
    color = 'black', linewidth = 0.5,
    labels=[True, False, False, False])
m.drawmeridians(
    np.arange(lllon, urlon, 2.),
    color = '0.25', linewidth = 0.5,
    labels=[False, False, False, True])

# contour plot
con = m.contourf(xi, yi, zi, zorder=4, alpha=0.6, cmap='RdPu')

# scatter plot
m.scatter(
    data['Lon'],
    data['Lat'],
    color='#545454',
    edgecolor='#ffffff',
    alpha=.75,
    s=50 * norm(data['Z']),
    cmap='RdPu',
ax=ax,
vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max(), zorder=4)

#Add colorbar
cbar = m.colorbar()
cbar.set_label("Mean Rainfall - mm")

m.drawmapscale(
    24., -9., 28., -13, 100,
    units='km', fontsize=10,
    yoffset=None,
    barstyle='fancy', labelstyle='simple',
    fillcolor1='w', fillcolor2='#000000',
    fontcolor='#000000',
    zorder=5)

plt.title("Mean Rainfall")
plt.savefig("rainfall.png", format="png", dpi=300, transparent=True)
plt.show()
  Lon     Lat     Z
32.59  -13.56  79.1
27.07  -16.84  50.5
32.68  -10.27  65.8
24.21  -13.60  66.5
28.47  -14.45  61.2
28.15  -12.61  76.5
27.92  -15.78  85.9
22.65  -15.00 101.2
24.80  -14.79  61.3
31.14  -10.22  50.7
26.00  -13.46  55.7
29.08   -9.79  88.2
25.82  -17.82  78.9
33.18  -12.29  87.1
28.45  -15.32  51.1
27.62  -16.00  48.2
28.87  -11.14  60.5
28.45  -15.32  59.9
28.79  -16.15  54.6
27.60  -16.00  59.4
31.55   -8.86  85.9
31.93  -13.25  47.1
31.55  -10.17  86.5
29.38  -13.60  69.6
23.15  -15.25  57.0
31.43  -11.90  84.0
32.57  -13.65  71.8
28.25  -15.55  65.7
27.19  -15.08  64.5
24.43  -11.74  90.0
28.66  -12.99  85.5
31.34  -14.25  72.0
29.91  -11.37  98.6
23.30  -16.11  41.9
30.21  -13.23  76.6
24.30  -17.48  44.3
26.37  -12.17  89.5
23.11  -13.53  57.2
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Arne for this link. I will work with it and it is a good starting point for me to learn.

Comment: With the edited gridding and interpolation I am getting the error:interp = RegularGridInterpolator((xg, yg, zg), data)
NameError: name 'xg' is not defined. help needed.

Comment: With the latest edit, the gridding works. I am able to print X, Y and Z interpolated values. I do not understand the plotting error:UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.  self.zmax = float(z.max())
 UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.   self.zmin = float(z.min())

Comment: The problem has been completely solved with the last edit of 20/09/2022